# How to get the status of a Comprehend Medical Job Request in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-comprehend

I am starting a Comprehend Medical Job Request using the `StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest` function.
In the documentation it says "To get the status of a job, use this(JobId) identifier with the DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2Job operation", however there is no operation called `DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2Job`, only `DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest` and `DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobResponse`.

How can I call `DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobResponse` (or any other function) to get the status of the job?

I was thinking something like this would work:

```
ComprehendMedicalAsyncJobProperties jobProperties = new ComprehendMedicalAsyncJobProperties()
                {
                    DataAccessRoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::1129587198257:role/role_name",
                    InputDataConfig = input,
                    OutputDataConfig = output
                };


                DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobResponse requestResponse = new DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobResponse()
                {
                    ComprehendMedicalAsyncJobProperties = jobProperties
                };
while(requestResponse.HttpStatusCode!=(*something that would indicate that the job is completed here*))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputDataConfig input = new InputDataConfig()
                    {
                        S3Bucket = "your_bucket_here",
                        S3Key = "subdirectory_name"
                    };
                    OutputDataConfig output = new OutputDataConfig()
                    {
                        S3Bucket = "your_bucket_here",
                        S3Key = "subdirectory_name"
                    };

                    StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest request = new StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest()
                    {
                        InputDataConfig = input,
                        JobName = "job_name_example",
                        LanguageCode = "en",
                        OutputDataConfig = output,
                        DataAccessRoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::12312512512:role/acces_role_name_here"
                    };
                    StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobResponse comprehendResult = comprehendClient.StartEntitiesDetectionV2JobAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest entitiesDetectionV2JobRequest = new DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobRequest()
                    {
                        JobId = comprehendResult.JobId
                    };

                    DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobResponse comprehendResult2 = comprehendClient.DescribeEntitiesDetectionV2JobAsync(entitiesDetectionV2JobRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```